# How to get black outlines in Blender 2.8 Workbench Render? Currently all my outline lines are white!

Tags: shaders, workbench-render-engine

I am trying to render out a cartoon version of the model shown in the image, but as you can see, I am getting white outlines when rendering using blender 2.8 workbench engine. I have set the outline color to black on both the workbench engine settings and Eevee engine settings so not sure what's going on here?

Also is there a way that I can make the line weight taper off at the end of the line so it looks more like a pen stroke and not a line?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Activate freeline in the General Scene settings (I am using eevee render engine)
[image]
Go to the image sequence settings and let's configure freestyle like the picture:
[image]
You´re going to select Thickness and then add a modifier ALONG STROKE.
[image]
And you want to select CURVE for the modifier. Now you need a profile curve.
Draw one like this:
[image]
"M" shape which means thick at the beginning, lower towards the middle, and thick again on the end line.

You can change the color and thickness here:
[image]

Don´t forget to change the line blending mode from MIX to ADD. Here are my settings:
[image]

The render:
[image]

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thanks works on Eevee, doesn't work with workbench!

Comment: Workbench is openGL. There is no freestyle with that.

Answer (score 4):

Blender 2.91. Works for colors other than black.

To get the Freestyle (FS) render pass, activate `Properties > View Layers > FS > As Render Pass`.

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually works in Workbench (rather than having to use Eevee).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same in Workbench (See image).
You can get outlines with tapering ends based on cavity.

Adjusting he thickness of this outline would be a great feature. Maybe someone can take this method to nodes??
I could'nt get the outer lines completely black either.

This approach could be a fast cartoon shader option in Blender 2.8!

[image: Outlines in Workbench]